# Flask, XAMPP - Apache, mod_wsgi,windows - installing mod_wsgi

Tags: python, windows, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to install mod_wsgi on my 64Bit anaconda environment, I set MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR to apache folder in XAMPP. Trying `pip install mod_wsgi` gave me error: `Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools'`, so installed it from given site. Now I can see the errors changed

```
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.cp3
6-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.
cp36-win_amd64.exp
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_brigade_f
latten
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_thread_mu
tex_create
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_ipsubnet_
test
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_pool_clea
nup_register
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_md5
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_time_now
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_itoa
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_server
_banner
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_hash_set
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_hook_trans
late_name
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_hash_make

    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_add_common
_vars
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_str_tolowe
r
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_set_conten
t_length
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_scoreboard
_image
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_mpm_query
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_palloc
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_satisfies
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_getword_co
nf
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_pstrndup
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_threadkey
_private_create
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_hash_over
lay
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_remote
_host
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_document_r
oot
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_some_auth_
required
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_no2slash
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_brigade_c
reate
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_strerror
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_table_mak
e
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_check_cmd_
context
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_brigade_d
estroy
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_table_elt
s
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_brigad
e
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_array_pus
h
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_server
_port
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_brigade_c
leanup
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_array_app
end
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_scoreb
oard_global
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_ipsubnet_
create
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_pstrdup
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_strtoi64
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_limit_
req_body
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_table_add

    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_escape_htm
l2
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_thread_mu
tex_lock
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_sockaddr_
info_get
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_hook_handl
er
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_register_p
rovider
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_discard_re
quest_body
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_pool_user
data_set
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_find_path_
info
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_regexec
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_pregsub
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucket_tr
ansient_create
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_add_versio
n_component
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_psprintf
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_hook_acces
s_checker
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_add_cgi_va
rs
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_table_uns
et
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_psignature

    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_thread_mu
tex_unlock
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_allow_opti
ons
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_server
_name
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_hook_child
_init
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_dynamic_f
n_retrieve
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_set_conten
t_type
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_log_error_

    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_pool_user
data_get
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_pstrcat
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucket_fl
ush_create
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucket_ty
pe_eos
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_off_t_toa

    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_log_rerror
_
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_array_mak
e
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_hash_get
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_hook_post_
config
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_table_get

    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_run_genera
te_log_id
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_pass_briga
de
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_pstrmemdu
p
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_table_set
n
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_pregcomp
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_stat
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_array_cat

    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_table_set

    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_pool_clea
nup_null
    wsgi_apache.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_conv_u
tf8_to_ucs2
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucke
t_shared_make
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucke
t_shared_copy
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucke
t_free
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucke
t_alloc
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucke
t_shared_destroy
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucke
t_shared_split
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_show_mp
m
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_ser
ver_description
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_ser
ver_built
    wsgi_metrics.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_sc
oreboard_process
    wsgi_metrics.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_sc
oreboard_worker_from_indexes
    wsgi_metrics.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_exists
_scoreboard_image
    wsgi_thread.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_thread
key_private_get
    wsgi_thread.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_thread
key_private_set
    build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\mod_wsgi\server\mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd : fatal
error LNK1120: 101 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I think the most important here is this:

```
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I'm using 64-bit Windows, 64-bit Python, XAMPP on Windows is by default 32-bit, so Apache in it is 32-bit too. What can be the cause of my problem?

Comment: Did you try `easy_install mod_wsgi`

Comment: Yes, it gave me same errors.

Comment: What Apache distribution are you using. Some Apache distributions for Windows do not provide everything required to build third party Apache modules. I can only confirm that Apache distribution from apachelounge.com works.

Comment: c:/xampp/apache/bin/httpd -v gives me this result: `Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32), Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul 9 2017 11:48:22`. I'm using a default version of Apache, providing by XAMPP Environment. Could it be changed?

Comment: I'm getting the same errors. The only difference is that I'm using the distribution from ApacheLounge. Did you happen to solve it?

Comment: Hey - I just solved this on my end. I _thought_ I was using the 64 bit version of python, but was actually using 32. Just to be sure, if you haven't, you can open the python app and `import platform` then `platform.architecture()` and it will tell you which one you're using.

I know it's a long shot - but I had the exact same errors - though way in the beginning of the output it mentioned something about "PLATFORM" that maybe should have been a clue. Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, because I have to use 64-bit Python as a recommended one for tensorflow library.

Comment: In[4]: platform.architecture()
Out[4]: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')